# Search through Linklist in Richtext field not working?

Tags: search, richtext

We launched a website last week based on Craft CMS.
One page contains mainly a list with links to sponsors (entered in a rich text field).

I make a fulltext search (via `$critera->search`) through the whole website, that works very fine, but it just didn't find the link texts inside a rich text field. (e.g. "Ascot", http://www.unidram.de/en/festival/partner-sponsors)

If I put the same text outside of the link, the search will find it. But that's not the solution, because the text should be the link.

I made a workaround and added Tags for every link to the page (except above given example). That did the job, but is additional work we won't normally do.

At first I clicked on "rebuild the search index".

The search on the website didn't find the page.
This is the template part of the search:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getPost('q') %}
{% set entries =  
 craft.entries.search(query).section('seitenstruktur').order('score') %}
```

Then I searched for 'Ascot' in `craft_searchindex` in the DB.

Part of the content of the related field is this:

```
performance netzuniversitaetsgesellschaft potsdam sponsorenhochdreiascot bristolmedienpartnerpotsdamer neueste nachrichten
```

While the content looks like this:

[image: content]

So in fact the word 'Ascot' is saved as part of 'sponsorenhochdreiascot'. 
As soon as I change it to 'sponsorenhochdrei ascot', the entry will be found by the search on the website.

The HTML Code of the part is:

```
<h3>Sponsoren</h3>
<p><a target="_blank" href="http://www.domainx.com/">HochDrei</a><br>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.domainy.de/">Ascot 
Bristol</a><br>
</p>
```

The search index seems to miss some space characters.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to search with? RTE fields get their data saved to `craft_searchindex` just like any other textual field. You can find the field ID for the field you're searching against and find the corresponding row in `craft_searchindex` to verify `ascot` is in the search data.

Comment: I made further tests. please sea the edited question, because comments just allow mini markdown formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that searching for `Ascot` doesn't match `sponsorenhochdreiascot` is because Craft doesn't do wildcard or fuzzy searching by default.

If you search for `*ascot` it would match.  You can all of the supported search syntaxes here: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching

**Update:**
As of [Craft 2.5](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2750), you can enable [fuzzy](https://craftcms.com/help/enabling-fuzzy-search-by-default) searching by default.

Comment: oahahh, damn. Sometimes one didnt see the simplest things. Thanks Brad!